# mail sites in iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, gmail, yahoo-mail

```
<style>
.address_bar
{
    width:1100px;
    color:#333333;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
\#browser
{
    width:90%;
}
</style>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function go_to_page()
    {
        var url = document.getElementById("address").value;
        //window.open(url,"browser");
        document.getElementById("browser").src = url;
    }
</script>



<body>  
<div>  
    <div style="float:left;">  
        <input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="address_bar" value="http://"/>    
    </div>    
    <div style="float:left;">  
        <input type="button" name="go" id="go" value="Go >> " onclick="go_to_page()"/>
    </div>  
    <div>  
        <iframe name="browser" id="browser" style="height:750px;">  
        </iframe>  
    </div>  
</div>  
</body>
```

---

In above example if I want to open 
1. http://mail.yahoo.com
2. http://www.gmail.com

then It automatically removes the iframe. what I do? I want every site is open in same iframe.

Comment: You respect the wishes of the site owner to not have their site wrapped in an iframe and move on.

Comment: The OP asks a valid and proper question, even though it may be naive and not possible. Don't downvote because you already know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These sites have what is called a *frame breakout*, to prevent them being loaded in a frame. There are some scripts to disable frame breakout, with varying results.

Of course, loading 3rd party sites in an frame within your own website is kind of stealing, and profiting of their success, but I trust that you just want a way to check both of your e-mail accounts.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. For security reasons, these websites won't load if they "know" they are in an iframe.